# Accessing Variables Specified for Jenkins Groovy Plugin Script

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When writing a script that is run by [Jenkins Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) as a build step (*Execute System Groovy Script*) one can specify 'variable bindings'. The helpline says: *Define varibale bingings (in the properties file format). Spefified variables can be addressed from the script.* [sic] How do I access those variables from the script? They are not set as environment variables for the build, neither are they present among System properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this.getBinding().getVariables()`

or simply `binding.variables`

Comment: Do you know how to access the environment variables in the script?

Comment: @Newbie, `binding.varaibles` is a [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) object (keyed by variable names).

Comment: If you have a binding like `foo=bar` in your variable bindings,  you can get `bar` by running `binding.variables.get('foo')`.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use binding.variables directly, I only got `listener`, `build`, `launcher` and `out` from binding.variables.

Instead I was able to use `build.environment(listener)` to retrieve the environment variables as suggested in the responses to this question:
[Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step ( Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236268/access-to-build-environment-variables-from-a-groovy-script-in-a-jenkins-build-st)

```
def config = new HashMap()
config.putAll(binding.variables)
def logger = config['out']
def envvars = new HashMap()
envvars.putAll(build.getEnvironment(listener))
def myvar= envvars['myvar']
```

This might have been different for me since I am only looking for system-wide environmental variables:

> (checked) Prepare an environment for the run \
>       Keep Jenkins Environment Variables  \   Keep Jenkins Build Variables