# Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step (Windows)

Tags: windows, groovy, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm using Scriptler plugin, so I can run a groovy script as a build step. My Jenkins slaves are running on windows in service mode. With scriptler, I don't need to use windows batch scripts.

But I have trouble to get the environment variables in a build step... This is working:

```
System.getenv("BASE")
```

Where `BASE` is part of the env-vars on jenkins startup. However, I would like to get

```
%JOB_NAME%
```

If I'm adding an "Execute Windows batch command" build step:

```
echo %JOB_NAME%
```

It works.
If I'm adding a scriptler script as a build step with the same settings:

```
println "JOB_NAME: " + System.getenv("JOB_NAME")
```

I'm getting:

```
JOB_NAME: null
```

So how can I reach the injected environment variables from a groovy script as a build step?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215394/how-to-get-environment-variable-in-jenkins-groovy-script-console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Scriptler Groovy script doesn't seem to get all the environment variables of the build. But what you can do is force them in as parameters to the script:

1. When you add the Scriptler build step into your job, select the option "Define script parameters"
2. Add a parameter for each environment variable you want to pass in. For example "Name: JOB_NAME", "Value: $JOB_NAME". The value will get expanded from the Jenkins build environment using '$envName' type variables, most fields in the job configuration settings support this sort of expansion from my experience.
3. In your script, you should have a variable with the same name as the parameter, so you can access the parameters with something like:

   println "JOB_NAME = $JOB_NAME"

I haven't used Sciptler myself apart from some experimentation, but your question posed an interesting problem. I hope this helps!

Comment: One problem with this approach (assuming the variable is set as MYVAR) is that groovy will "blow up" if the value is not provided as a parameter.  To see what WAS passed you can try this:
```
println "--> The following values were provided: "
this.binding.variables.each {k,v -> println "$k = '$v'"}
```

Answer (score 63):

`build` and `listener` objects are presenting **during system groovy execution**. You can do this:

```
def myVar = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('myVar')
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the only way to get access to the env vars in a "Execute System Groovy Script" build step.

Comment: doesn't work for me, get "Problems occurs on injecting env vars as a build wrap: null". No additional error details, how to debug this situation?

Comment: The question states "I'm using Scriptler plugin..." and this requires system groovy execution so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Scriptler is a script storage with possibility to use it in any way you want. So statement that "scriptler" requires only "system groovy execution" is wrong.

Comment: what is `listener` in this case?

Comment: listener is an object passed to perform() that available during build execution.

Comment: There is no perform() call here. `listener` is an instance of [TaskListener](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/TaskListener.html). In a simple case like this, you can just use [`TaskListener.NULL`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/TaskListener.html#NULL) instead of `listener` in the above snippet.

Comment: I get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: WorkflowScript` when trying this from within a function.

Comment: @micseydel try the alternative I provided in the edit.

Answer (score 20):

You might be able to get them like this:

```
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable
def envVarsMap = build.parent.builds[0].properties.get("envVars")
```

Comment: in windows envVarsMap  is giving null for some env variables ? any idea why?

Comment: Tested with jenkins v2.190.2 in a shared lib:
`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread`

Answer (score 17):

On jenkins 2.x, with groovy plugin 2.0, running **SystemGroovyScript** I managed to get to build variables, as below:

```
def build = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('build')
def listener = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('listener')
def env = build.getEnvironment(listener)
println env.MY_VARIABLE
```

If you are using goovy from file, simple `System.getenv('MY_VARIABLE')` is sufficient

Comment: I found that this also works in Jenkins 2.89: `def env = binding.build.environment; println env.FOO`

Comment: @AllanLewis I'm getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: groovy.lang.Binding`... Any suggestion?

Comment: @MarcellodeSales in what context?

Comment: @AllanLewis on a Global Shared Library... I was only able to use the global property as in https://build.intuit.com/services-config/pipeline-syntax/globals#env. See my answer

Comment: @MarcellodeSales You're right, my solution won't work in a shared library, only in a Groovy script executed directly in the context of a build. I guess your library function could take the build as a parameter.

Comment: I found the JavaDoc to be helpful: https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html.

Answer (score 6):

The only way I could get this to work (on Linux) was to follow this advice:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+System+Groovy+script

```
import hudson.model.*

// get current thread / Executor and current build
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thr?.executable

// if you want the parameter by name ...
def hardcoded_param = "FOOBAR"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def hardcoded_param_value = resolver.resolve(hardcoded_param)

println "param ${hardcoded_param} value : ${hardcoded_param_value}"
```

This is on Jenkins 1.624 running on CentOS 6.7

Answer (score 6):

Jenkins 2.x has the global variables. `env` is one of them from any script...

```
println env.JOB_NAME
```

More at https://build.intuit.com/services-config/pipeline-syntax/globals#env

Comment: This is for pipeline right?  The question is about the Scriptler plugin.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note, if you are using a freestyle job, you won't be able to access build parameters or the Jenkins JVM's environment UNLESS you are using System Groovy Script build steps.  I spent hours googling and researching before gathering enough clues to figure that out.

Comment: This is also applicable in Linux

Answer (score 0):

In **System Groovy Script** (Jenkins 2.89), I was able to use the environmental variable to disable another Jenkins job

```
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
def env = binding.build.environment
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(env.job_name).setDisabled(false)
```

I also added a conditional step so as to either enable or disable another Jenkins job.

[image]

Thanks @Allan Lewis, your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked for me is [How to get environment variable in Jenkins Groovy script console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215394/how-to-get-environment-variable-in-jenkins-groovy-script-console)

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
def envVars = Jenkins.instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()[0].getEnvVars() 
println envVars['myVar']
```