# Accessing Jenkins custom Build Parameter using Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build job where I am passing few parameters while triggering the job.
I need to use some of those parameters in a Groovy script.
How to do that?

My Parameter is BUG_ID and its value is 2010

I am accessing as shown below

```
print ('BUILD_NO is '+System.getenv('BUG_ID'))
print ('BUILD_NO is ${BUG_ID}')
print ('BUILD_NO is ${env.BUG_ID}')
```

All returning null

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236268/access-to-build-environment-variables-from-a-groovy-script-in-a-jenkins-build-st ?

Comment: Are you running this as a standalone Groovy script from shell, the Groovy postbuild plugin or some other way?

Comment: try `print ('BUILD_NO is ' + BUG_ID)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```
print ("BUILD_NO is ${BUG_ID}")
```