# How can I run two gmaven scripts in one pom.xml?

Tags: maven, gmaven-plugin

I want to have two scripts run from maven, one of which depends on an environment variable. I'm trying something like this:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <source>
            println "My script"
          </source>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>

...

<profile>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>env.MY_ENV_VAR</name>
      <value>runStuff</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>
                 println "My conditional script" 
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>          
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

When I run "mvn validate" to test this, I get "My script". When I set the env variable and run it again, I get "My conditional script" but **not** "My script". It seems that if the condition is satisfied and the second one runs, the first one will not.

I want to run the first one unconditionally **and** the second one only if the env variable is set. I thought of checking the env variable in the script itself but that seems problematic too, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236268/access-to-build-environment-variables-from-a-groovy-script-in-a-jenkins-build-st).

I'm new to maven so it's not unlikely there's a simple solution but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Each execution must have a unique ID. If you don't specify an ID, you get 'default' for both. Once I gave the conditional one a non-default ID, they both run.

```
<build>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    ...
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>Unconditional-script</id>
        ...
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>

...

<profile>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        ...
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Conditional-script</id>
            ...
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>          
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```