# How to access global environment through groovy script in Jenkins Pipeline Plugin

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In shell we use following command

```
  node{
     sh "x=${env.j_properties_file}"
     sh "y=${env.HOME}"
  }
```

How do we it in groovy script Or How do we access shell variable x in groovy script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step ( Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236268/access-to-build-environment-variables-from-a-groovy-script-in-a-jenkins-build-st)

Comment: Im not exactly clear on what you are asking. Can you clarify a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't access them directly, but according to the [reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script)
you can catch stdout from your `sh` step:

```
node{
    def xx = sh(returnStdout:true, script:"""
        x=${env.j_properties_file}
        echo \${x}
    """)

    echo "the shell output = ${xx}"
}
```