# Jenkins Environment Variables in Groovy Init

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, amazon-ecs

I am building a Docker image of Jenkins, and have passed ENV variables to the `jenkins.sh` initialization file:

**Dockerfile**

```
...

COPY ./jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
```

**jenkins.sh**

```
echo ENV: "$ENV"
echo CLUSTER: "$CLUSTER"
echo REGION: "$REGION"
```

When I run the image, these values print out perfectly, but I would like to use them in Groovy scripts during the initialization of Jenkins.

The following throws an error during start:

```
import java.util.Arrays
import java.util.logging.Logger
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ecs-cluster")

logger.info("Loading Archeus-Midwayer...")
import jenkins.model.*
instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def env = System.getenv()
println(env['CLUSTER'])
```

**Error**

> WARNING: Failed to run script file:/var/jenkins_home/init.groovy.d/init_ecs.groovy
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CLUSTER for class: init_ecs
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)

How can I capture the environment variables present in `jenkins.sh`?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you iterate over `env` with `env.each { println it }`? Are there any? What if you `export` env vars in `jenkins.sh`? Are those available in Groovy then?

Comment: So exporting didn't work (sorta expected as I think exports are scoped to the shell), but the `env.each { println it }` shows it.  Why wouldn't env['CLUSTER'] work?

Comment: Ok, I think I jumped the gun exporting works.  Thanks Gerold!

Comment: Perhaps [Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step ( Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21236268/1744774) may help, too.

Comment: I am not sure there is a 'build' concept when the init.groovy.d files run, is there?  Or I wasn't sure how to construct a build object.  I also got it working by using `sed -i "1s/^/CLUSTER=\"${CLUSTER}\" \n/" /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/init_ecs.groovy`, but I prefer the exports. :)

Comment: You're right. I've never used a [Post-initialization script](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script), wasn't even aware of it and since you didn't link to it... ;) However, thanks for teaching me something and glad that I could be of help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the env vars with:

```
def env = System.getenv()
env.each { 
  println it
}
```

[Export](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) the env vars in `jenkins.sh`.

See also  [Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step ( Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21236268/1744774).