# How to get Jenkins build parameters in the Groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In Jenkins, I am using ‘Validation String Parameter’ as one input parameter ‘COMPANY_NAME’.

I need to get it in groovy script in Build secion.
Using the below code, I am unable to get the my custom build parameter.

import hudson.model.*

def companyName= System.getenv(“COMPANY_NAME”)

It returns null.
How to get Jenkins build parameters in the Groovy script?

Comment: i would turn that into an answer and mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It worked using the below groovy code.

**Working Code**

```
 def build = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('build')
 def listener = this.getProperty('binding').getVariable('listener')
 def env = build.getEnvironment(listener) 
 println "COMPANY_NAME = "+ env.COMPANY_NAME
```

Referred  - [Access to build environment variables from a groovy script in a Jenkins build step (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236268/access-to-build-environment-variables-from-a-groovy-script-in-a-jenkins-build-st)